# Load web page from input field on button click in iframe

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I want to get URL from user in input field. Then I want to load that URL in iframe when the user clicks the LOAD button. Here is what I have done so far  I tried to load the URL in iframe but failed. please help ! I am first time user of HTMl and Web stuff.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("ur").value;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;

}
```

```html
<h3>Enter the URl in input field</h3>

<p>Click the button to get the url displayed in the iframe.</p>



<form>
  Enter the URL: <input id="ur" type="text" name="url"><br>
  <input type="button" id="myBtn" onclick="myFunction()" value="Load">
</form>


<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `iframe` `src` like this:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("ur").value;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
  document.getElementById('myIframe').src = x;
}
```

```html
<h3>Enter the URl in input field</h3>

<p>Click the button to get the url displayed in the iframe.</p>

<form>
  Enter the URL: <input id="ur" type="text" name="url"><br>
  <input type="button" id="myBtn" onclick="myFunction()" value="Load">
</form>

<iframe id="myIframe" src="https://stackoverflow.com" width="500" height="200"></iframe>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Note that you can not see many websites in iframe because those set `X-Frame-Options` to deny!

Comment: When I load stackoverflow , nothing is displayed in my iframe.
When I tried to load https://www.adobe.com, iframe displayed a message "www.adobe.com refused to connect"

Comment: @irumzahra I told you in my last word, you can not display many websites in iframe because they block it! do a google about iframe X-Frame-Options

Answer (score 0):

Update your function to this. use createElement of javascript to create and append in body. you can change it to append after any other element.

```
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("ur").value;
  var ifrm = document.createElement("iframe");
  ifrm.setAttribute("src", x);
  ifrm.style.width = "640px";
  ifrm.style.height = "480px";
  document.body.appendChild(ifrm);
}
```

Comment: Tried it as well. one problem is: When I load stackoverflow , nothing is displayed in my iframe. When I tried to load adobe.com, iframe displayed a message "www.adobe.com refused to connect"

Comment: second is that everytime i enter new url it makes new frame for that